Addressing Scaling Bias in Panel Data Analysis
I am running an (unbalanced) panel data analysis, where the dependent variable is, $fixed\ cost\ (per\ ha)$ for an agricultural firm $i$ in period $t$. The explanatory variables are the hectares per crop, for crop A, crop B and crop C.
$fixed\ cost\ (per\ ha)_{it} = hect\ crop\ A_{it} + hect\ crop\ B_{it} + hect\ crop\ C_{it}$
The dependent variable is expressed per hectare, because it has the preferred interpretation. However I am suspecting an issue when the crops are also expressed in hectares.
Will the coefficients on the crops $A, B$ and $C$ (which show the effect of ceteris paribus increase of 1 hectare for that crop), measure the effect of that increase in $A$, $B$, $C$ on a dependent variable which is divided by that extra hectare?
If that is the case, that would cause problems, because it likely creates a negative relation between crops hectares and costs, because it shows the effect when the denominator is increased by a hectare.
What is really of interest is much more a shift of 1 hectare in crop A, to another crop, keeping the total amount of hectares constant.
How can I specify my model to reflect this?
Should it be something like:
$fixed\ cost\ (per\ ha)_{it} = (hect\ crop\ A\ \div tot\ hect)_{it} + (hect\ crop\ B\ \div tot\ hect)_{it} + (hect\ crop\ C\ \div tot\ hect)_{it}$
Where I instead use the percentages of the crops and total hectares, or even:
$fixed\ cost_{it} = (hect\ crop\ A\ \div tot\ hect)_{it} + (hect\ crop\ B\ \div tot\ hect)_{it} + (hect\ crop\ C\ \div tot\ hect)_{it}$
I however also assume, that when I use ratios, I cannot use all three of them? Because they would add up to 100%.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.
